# How can I see a full view of a datatable?

Tags: c#, oledb

So I have read in a .xls file into a data table.  Created a new table with a schema that matches a database table.  Then iterate through each row/column and assign the correct data to the fields of the new data-table.

The last piece is passing the data-table as a parameter to a stored proc to process to a temp table which will then get merged with the actual table in the database.

My question is (for testing purposes) how can I easily write out (or view) the contents of new data-table to verify its contents and structure before I proceed to pass onto the Stored proc?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`WriteXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbadk5ed.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

Why not check it out in the debugger?  There should be a little magnifying glass icon which will display the contents of your data table (unless you are using an old Visual Studio version).

See [Visualizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 You can try the [Data Visualizer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/datadebuggervisualizer.aspx).

It works in Visual Studio 2005/2008 and will graphically display a DataTable's contents  showing edited/deleted/added cells and rows.  The tool also works with DataSets, typed DataSets, DataViews and DataRows.

Answer (score 0):

You could just databind a GridView to your datatable and view the results there.  Here is a good post that goes over doing that:

http://programming.top54u.com/post/ASP-Net-Bind-GridView-to-DataTable.aspx

In his example he manually creates all of the columns.  You could probably get away with just setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to true and databinding.

Depending on the number of rows you are dealing with you might want to add paging.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand how to bind the data to a grid on the view (web form) - but since the form called the web method on a separate web service, how do I pass the datatable object back to the form AND intercept it with the logic in the code behind of that form that does the binding?